# Vetor e Classes,sorteando e preenchendo vetor em Java

Tags: java, classes

Estou fazendo um exercício que é necessário criar um vetor de 10 nomes,e que tenha 3 métodos.
O primeiro método é chamado **cadastrarNome**,e tem como função preencher os vetores,o segundo método é chamado **sortearNome** que retorna uma String(que tem objetivo de sortear os nomes),e o terceiro método chamado **exibirNome** que tem como função exibir os nomes sorteados.
Eu estou com certas dúvidas em relação aos 3 métodos,se vocês puderem me ajudar eu irei agradecer,irei colocar aqui em baixo certas partes do código,pelo menos a estrutura dele.

Aqui esta o código somente com um escopo mesmo :

```
package Testes;

public class ClasseSorteio {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
         String nomeSorteado[] = new String[10];




    }

    public void cadastrarNome() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    }

    }

    public String sortearNome(String nome) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {


        }

        return nome;
    }


    public void exibirNome() {


    }

}
```

Na classe Principal eu terei que usar JOptionPane,e terei que ter 3 botões : **Cadastrar Nome,Sortear Nome e Exibir Nome**,cada botão chamando um método.

OBS :Me desculpem realmente,se o código não tem praticamente nada pronto,eu realmente estou com dúvidas nesta parte dos 3 métodos,por que comecei agora a aprender sobre métodos.

Desde já agradeço por terem a paciência com este meu post nada arrumado.

Comment: Olá, @Falino. Seja bem vindo. Parece que sua dúvida não é sobre métodos ou classes e sim sobre algoritmos. Sugiro que faça uma pergunta de cada vez sobre as coisas que têm dúvida.

Comment: Olá amigo,sim na verdade a dúvida mesmo é sobre vetor.No curso de Programação que estou fazendo,nós aprendemos vetor e matriz bem pouco mesmo,focamos mais nesta parte de Classe e Métodos.É um curso profissional mesmo,mas mesmo assim foi pouco tempo para aprender vetor,e por causa disto estou com muitas dúvidas.

Comment: Então, @Falion. Sugiro que faça uma pegunta para cada dúvida que você tiver, para que sua pergunta se encaixe no formato do SO em português. Por exemplo: "Como sortear um elemento de um vetor". Dessa forma você vai até mesmo descobrir que já existem soluções para suas dúvidas aqui mesmo no SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A verdade é que você não deu informações suficientes para resolver o seu problema, mas já fez quase 1 ano que postou esse problema, e vou tentar dar uma resposta.

## Indexação de arrays

É importante mencionar que um array é um contentar que armazena vários valores. Para obter e definir um valor no array é preciso referir qual a posição do array onde esse valor está/vai estar.

Em java os arrays são indexados a partir do 0. A sintaxe para indexar um array é utilizando `[]`. Logo, para obter o primeiro elemento do array a instrução é `arr[0]`

## Inicialização de arrays

Os arrays em java podem ser inicializados de várias formas, á semelhança de todos os outros tipos, podem ser inicializados de duas formas:

### Com valores constantes

```
String nomeSorteado[] = new String[10]{
  "Pessoa1", "Pessoa2", "Pessoa3", "Pessoa4", "Pessoa5",
  "Pessoa6", "Pessoa7", "Pessoa8", "Pessoa9", "Pessoa10"
};
```

### Com valores dinamicos

```
String nomeSorteado[] = new String[10];
for(int i = 0; i < nomeSorteado.length; ++i){
   nomeSorteado[i] = <valor dinamico vai aqui>
}
```

Esses valores dinamicos podem ser obtidos de várias formas: Input do utilizador, valores gerados aleatóriamente, lidos de uma fonte de dados (ficheiros, base de dados) e assim adiante.

Agora podemos resolver o seu problema, vou resove-lo usando valores constantes.

```
public class ClasseSorteio {
    //Nota que tive que criar um campo para poder acessar ao array em todos os metodos
    private String[] nomeSorteado = new String[10]{
      "Pessoa1", "Pessoa2", "Pessoa3", "Pessoa4", "Pessoa5",
      "Pessoa6", "Pessoa7", "Pessoa8", "Pessoa9", "Pessoa10"
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        ClasseSorteio sorteio = new ClasseSorteio();
        sorteio.cadastrarNome();
        String nome = sorteio.sortearNome();
        sorteio.exibirNome(nome);
    }

    public void cadastrarNome() {
        //não faz nada porque estou a usar valores constantes
    }

    //Nota que eu removi o parametro. 
    //Se o seu objetivo é sortear um nome no array aleatoriamente, 
    //não faz sentido passar o nome como parametro
    public String sortearNome() {
        Random r = new Random();
        int idx = r.nextInt(nomeSorteado.length);
        return nomeSorteado[idx];
    }

    //Nota que eu acrescentei o parametro.
    //Para mostrar um nome é preciso saber qual é o nome...
    public void exibirNome(String nome) {
        System.out.println(nome);
    }
}
```